# Razor If-condition not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, if-statement, razor

I can't seem to get the if-condition of a String comparison to work. Here is the code for my foreach block.

```
@foreach (var item in Model){               

<tr onclick="getData('@item.DiscountDescs');">                            
    <td></td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DiscountDescs)</td>


    <td>
        @if (string.Equals(item.DiscountForm, "C"))
        {
            @:Card
        }
        else
        { 
            @:Other
        }
    </td>


    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DiscountType)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DiscountMode)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DiscountValue)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsActive)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsScheme)</td>
</tr>
}
```

The td display would always be "Other".

Comment: What is the value of item.DiscountForm ?

Comment: C and O from the database.

Comment: Use Trim function item.DiscountForm.Trim()

Comment: I am posting this as answer please mark as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to trim the value coming from database.

Use `Trim()` function

```
item.DiscountForm.Trim()
```

This will omit extra spaces and will compare with string.